# Set heartbeat via command line in hadoop

Tags: hadoop

It is possible to set the heartbeat of the nodemanager  parameter via command line in hadoop ?

How ?

In alternative is possible to modify such parameter without restart the cluster ?

The parameter I am interested in manage is `yarn.resourcemanager.nodemanagers.heartbeat-interval-ms` under yarn-default.xml

Comment: I am sorry, question is not clear. Which heartbeat do you want to modify?

Comment: Sorry, I am refering to the `yarn.resourcemanager.nodemanagers.heartbeat-interval-ms` under yarn-default.xml

Comment: Checked, very clear, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set this parameter `yarn.resourcemanager.nodemanagers.heartbeat-interval-ms` (indicates `The heart-beat interval in milliseconds for every NodeManager in the cluster.`) using command line.

You can change this parameter in `yarn-site.xml` and then you need to re-start the services.

The reason being, this parameter is read once, when the `Resource Tracker Service` is started in the `Resource Manager`. The heart beat interval is returned to the `Node Manager`, as part of `NodeHeartbeatResponse`.

```
// Heartbeat response
NodeHeartbeatResponse nodeHeartBeatResponse = YarnServerBuilderUtils
    .newNodeHeartbeatResponse(lastNodeHeartbeatResponse.
        getResponseId() + 1, NodeAction.NORMAL, null, null, null, null,
        nextHeartBeatInterval);
```

The parameter `nextHeartBeatInterval` in the call above, is read in `serviceInit()` method of `Resource Tracker Service`:

```
nextHeartBeatInterval =
    conf.getLong(YarnConfiguration.RM_NM_HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS,
        YarnConfiguration.DEFAULT_RM_NM_HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS);
if (nextHeartBeatInterval <= 0) {
  throw new YarnRuntimeException("Invalid Configuration. "
      + YarnConfiguration.RM_NM_HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS
      + " should be larger than 0.");
}
```

Also, the value of `yarn.resourcemanager.nodemanagers.heartbeat-interval-ms` (default `1000`) should be less than value of `yarn.nm.liveness-monitor.expiry-interval-ms` (default `600000`). `yarn.nm.liveness-monitor.expiry-interval-ms` indicates `How long to wait until a node manager is considered dead.`.

The check for this is in `validateConfigs()` method of the Resource Manager:

```
// validate expireIntvl >= heartbeatIntvl
long expireIntvl = conf.getLong(YarnConfiguration.RM_NM_EXPIRY_INTERVAL_MS,
    YarnConfiguration.DEFAULT_RM_NM_EXPIRY_INTERVAL_MS);
long heartbeatIntvl =
    conf.getLong(YarnConfiguration.RM_NM_HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS,
        YarnConfiguration.DEFAULT_RM_NM_HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS);
if (expireIntvl < heartbeatIntvl) {
  throw new YarnRuntimeException("Nodemanager expiry interval should be no"
      + " less than heartbeat interval, "
      + YarnConfiguration.RM_NM_EXPIRY_INTERVAL_MS + "=" + expireIntvl
      + ", " + YarnConfiguration.RM_NM_HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS + "="
      + heartbeatIntvl);
}
```